# Why isn't a type constraint of "where T : object" compiling in C# 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

According to https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-8.0/nullable-reference-types-specification.md `object` is now a valid type constraint.

> Nullable reference types can be used as generic constraints. Furthermore object is now valid as an explicit constraint. Absence of a constraint is now equivalent to an object? constraint (instead of object), but (unlike object before) object? is not prohibited as an explicit constraint.

I would think that this should compile correctly but Visual Studio will not let me compile this.

```cs
public class A<T> where T : object { }
```

Am I misreading this or is this an issue with VS or C#8?

**UPDATE**

I am trying to define an interface for a cache.

```cs
public interface IDataCache
{
    void Put<T>(string key, T value) where T : notnull;
    T? Get<T>(string key) where T : notnull;
}
```

Ideally, I would not want a null value to be cached but I also cannot guarantee a value is going to be in the cache.  Sometimes I want to cache a class but other times it might be an integer.  Is this possible to achieve or do I have to make separate method for each case?

```cs
public interface IDataCache
{
    void Put<T>(string key, T value) where T : notnull;

    // This seems really nasty!
    T? GetClass<T>(string key) where T : class;
    T? GetStruct<T>(string key) where T : struct;
}
```

Comment: *"/proposals"*. *"This is a work in progress - several parts are missing or incomplete."*

Comment: The feature 'object generic type constraint' is currently in Preview and currently "unsupported." To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill on the contrary, C# 8 and .NET Core 3 have a Go Live license for the last couple of months, and the final release is only 2 weeks away. People are already using it in production. This is a valid question - did that feature make it to C# 8 or not?

Comment: This is a very good question - how do you specify nullability in generics? C# 8 already has a Go Live licence, so it *is* supported. The feature is still there, with a different syntax

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos That was the text of the error Visual Studio 2019 gave me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a valid question and the answer is *not* trivial. Things have changed a lot since the initial proposal, for valid reasons. Using the `object?` syntax would lead to confusion in other places.

The link points to the proposal document, not the actual documentation or specification. You'll find the documentation in the C# Guide's [Nullable Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references). There's no referecence to generic constraints there. The [Constraints on type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) article doesn't mention `object?` either, but it does mention the `notnull` constaint.

The changes and the reasons behind them are explained in [Try out Nullable Reference Types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-out-nullable-reference-types/).

**The common case: Nulls allowed**

This :

```
public class A<T>
{
    T DoStuff(T input)
    {
        return input;
    }
}
```

Accepts any struct or value type, including null types. The following line doesn't generate any warnings :

```
var x=new A<string?>();
```

**notnull constraint**

You have to specify that you want non-nullable types with the `notnull` constraint :

```
public class A<T>
    where T:notnull
{
    T DoStuff(T input)
    {
        return input;
    }
}
```

Using `string?` as a type parameter creates a warning now:

> warning CS8714: The type 'string?' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'A'. Nullability of type argument 'string?' doesn't match 'notnull' constraint.

**The problem with T?**

To use *nullable* types you have to specify whether the type is a class or struct. The reason for this is explained in [`The issue with T?` section](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-out-nullable-reference-types/) of the blog post that introduced NRTs. `T?` implies that `T` is non-nullable so what is `T`? Class or Struct? The compiler handles each case differently. With a struct, the compiler will generate a `Nullable<T>` type while classes are handled by compiler magic.

This code :

```
public class A<T>
{
    T? DoStuff(T input)
    {
        return input;
    }
}
```

Will throw a compiler error, not just a warning :

> A nullable type parameter must be known to be a value type or non-nullable reference type. Consider adding a 'class', 'struct', or type constraint.

Adding the `class` constraint and passing `string` as the type parameter doesn't generate any errors or warnings :

```
public class A<T>
    where T:class
{
    T? DoStuff(T input)
    {
        return input;
    }
}

var x=new A<string>();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and I understand the problem with T? although if I am understanding it correctly this leaves me with more questions.  I have updated my original question with what I am actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @jws305 if you don't want `null`s why return T? from `Get`? Returning `null` to specify a missing value isn't a great idea. That's why many collection methods have a `TryGet` or `TryXXX` method that returns true and the actual value in an output variable. Another option is to return a value tuple, eg `(T,bool)` from `Get`. Return `(default,false)` if the value is missing, `(value,true)` if found

Comment: I suppose the whole point of the new nullable reference types is to get away from using null to specify a missing value.  I will go with the TryGet method. Thanks!